# problem while importing Java classes

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I need to import the fallowing,But in blackberry there is no predefined imports as i need.

```
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javacard.framework.SystemException;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.kobjects.base64.Base64;
```

all these shows error.

When i add jar6 library it does n't show any error but i got packing failed.

I need to import these files.

can any one please post how can i import these files.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BlackBerry uses J2ME which is Java 1.3.  You won't be able to use Java 6 classes.  Instead you should look at the [BlackBerry API](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/).  It has classes for encryption but you'll need to rewrite your code to use them.